# Speed-up linear regression using coeftest in R

Tags: r, linear-regression

I developed an R code that requires to compute more than 10 million times the same multiple regression model (15 variables). I need to extract for each model the obtained *t*-statistic for only one independent variable. I need to apply for each model a heteroskedasticity-consistent covariance matrix estimator and I am doing that using the White's estimator via `coeftest` and `vcovHC`, but I noticed that this operation increases a lot the required computational time of the simulation. Therefore I was wondering if there could be a way to speed up the code as I only need the *t*-statistic of the second variable.

Below is a toy example of what I am doing at each iteration:

```
   model <- lm(y ~ a + b + c, data = data)
   model <- coeftest(model, vcov. = vcovHC(model, type = "HC"))
   t[i] <- summary(MUR)$coef[2, 3]
```

The variables involved are always the same, but I am permuting their values randomly. In other words I am permuting the model matrix *X*.

Comment: Is it the same regressors, but different dependent variables? If you break down what happens in these function calls, you will see that the core is basically a couple of matrix multiplications, wrapped up into a lot of function calls. You can speed indeed this up by writing it up in terms of pure linear algebra operations. In particular if it is the same regressors, since then you have to compute `(X'X)^-1 X'` only once.

Comment: @coffeinjunky in general you don't want to use the Normal equations to calculate linear regressions. Use QR decomposition.

Comment: The variables involved are always the same, but I am permuting their values randomnly. In other words I am permuting the model matrix X. How could I write the matrix product that produces the value of t for one of the covariates (taking into account the White correction), please?

Comment: Well, one way to speed this up is to avoid costly function calls and brake it down to linear algebra operations, where `R` is really fast. So, instead of calling `lm`, `coeftest`, etc, just write it up yourself. The operations behind these things are well known. See e.g. Wikipedia for robust standard errors. At some point you may have to form sums, where `rowsum` might be helpful. Keep in mind though that it comes at a cost. These function calls (checking of input etc) are there for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to reduce computation by ~30 % handling heteroscedasticity-corrected covariance matrices using `hccm` function of `car` package then extracting *t*-values directly. Please see the simulation below:

```
library(lmtest)
library(sandwich)
library(microbenchmark)
library(ggplot2)
library(car)

microbenchmark(
    hccm =   {
    m <- lm(cty ~ displ + cyl, data = mpg)
    V <- hccm(m, "hc0")
    cfs <- m$coefficients
    ses <- sqrt(diag(V))
    cfs / ses
  },
  coeftest = {
    m <- lm(cty ~ displ + cyl, data = mpg) 
    coeftest(m, vcov. = vcovHC(m, type = "HC0"))
  }
)
```

Output:

```
Unit: milliseconds
     expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
     hccm 1.695146 1.777919 1.939631 1.822293 1.891840 10.65045   100  a 
 coeftest 2.557013 2.650025 2.735701 2.684586 2.764373  3.37536   100   b
```